# url structure for mobile/desktop site

Tags: url, mobile-website

What are the pros and cons of these url formats for a website that does mobile and desktop content...

- mobile.example.com
- example.com/mobile
- no explicit url, but send back dynamic content based on browser, or querystring variable?

thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a "best."  But regardless, the answer to this question is likely going to be a subjective one.  Please consider making this a "community wiki" by checking the community wiki box.

Comment: Why do you have to chose one? Why not a combination? Although browser detection may be too fragile to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3 recommends "When accessing site entry points users should not have to enter a filename as part of the URI. If possible, configure Web sites so that they can be accessed without having to specify a sub-domain as part of the URI."

So m.example.com or example.com/m would be best solution